# How to not use 'this' in method in constructor

Tags: java

I have a question.

For optimisation of old java code, i'm looking for how to not using the "this" parameter called in the principal constructor.

For now i have:

```
public Class ConsultationDemandeUtilisationPointsViewImpl() extends Composite {  

  Driver driver = GWT.create(Driver.class);
  
  public ConsultationDemandeUtilisationPointsViewImpl() {

    initChamps();
    initFormulaire();
    initFormatage();
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    driver.initialize(this);
  }  
};
```

In other object, i can externalize some parameters and so make an other private constructor like `MyClass(parameter 1, parameter2, ...)` like this

```
public Class RechercherPaiementDetailleViewImpl extends AbstractPaiementViewImpl() {

  Driver driver = GWT.create(Driver.class);
  
  public RechercherPaiementDetailleViewImpl() {
    
    RechercherPaiementDetailleViewImpl rechercherPaiementDetailleViewImpl = new RechercherPaiementDetailleViewImpl(PaiementsDetaillesDataGrid.ModeDataGrid.RECHERCHE_PAIEMENT_DETAILLE);

    /** Initialisation du Widget **/
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(rechercherPaiementDetailleViewImpl));        
    driver.initialize(rechercherPaiementDetailleViewImpl);

  }

  private RechercherPaiementDetailleViewImpl(ModeDataGrid mode){    
    
    /** Initialisation des champs de champs de saisie du formulaire de recherche **/
    initChampsSaisie();

    /** Tableau du Résultat de la recherche Multi Critères **/
    resultatRechercheDataGrid = new NavigableDataGridWidget<SuiviPaiementUiDTO>(new PaiementsDetaillesDataGrid<SuiviPaiementUiDTO>(mode));
    resultatRechercheDataGrid.getDataGrid().initialiser();
        
    initFormulaire();
    initHandlers();
        
    /** Initalisation de l'affichage **/
    initAffichage();
    
  }
};
```

but in the 1st exemple, i just can't find solution to externalise "this" in an other method or constructor because i have not any param to do it.

Thanks in advance for all of your advices !

Baptiste

@David

Here it is a real exemple:

Comment: You're not going to see any performance benefit from this. You also don't need to pass "this" because each of those methods would have access to "this" if they're not static methods.

Comment: @Jason the problem i have here in the first exemple is not about performance but about full construct object. I can't be sure if my object is fully construct before pass him as param to a method

Comment: @B.Champaux: You can't be sure if the object is fully constructed because you are *in the constructor* and *currently constructing* the object.  Why do you need to pass `this` to a method on the object itself?  What exactly is the problem you're encountering?  It's not really clear what you're trying to ask.  Can you provide a real example which demonstrates that problem?

Comment: @David just edited with my real code. Hope this will help :)

Comment: @B.Champaux: It's still not clear what it is you're trying to do or what isn't working.  Though creating an instance of an object *in its own constructor* sounds like a recipe for problems.  This can easily lead to overflowing the stack with an infinite recursion of object construction.  Besides that it's not clear what is achieved by this.  When creating an instance of something, you first create a *different* instance of it, pass *that* instance to some methods, and then never do anything with it?  What is the goal here?

Comment: @David; Everything works fine in the first code. It's just for optimisation and to be sure the object ('this' in the 1st exemple) is fully construct. In the 2nd when i initialize the object, i'm sure it's fully construct and i have an entire object to pass to the method. But maybe i'm wrong ? I'm just here for get some advices :)

Comment: @B.Champaux: "Optimize" in what way?  Be specific about what you're asking.  If the code works, what are you trying to change and why?  When you attempt to make that change, what specific attempt do you make and how does it not work as expected?  For tips and information on how to ask a question, please read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: @David: to add some precisions, it's an old project i just get and sonar get error like this: Avoid to use this within Constructor in multi-thread environment

Comment: I don't think a GWT UI is multi threaded. I would ignore Sonar in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to make a private constructor and call it from within a factory method? Within the 'factory' you first create an instance, and then pass that instance as an argument to other constructors or methods as needed, and lastly return this instance to the caller of the factory method.

Here is a quick, simplistic example of the basic idea.

```
class Foo {
    private Foo() {
        // initialization code
    }

    static public Foo fooFactory(Bar bar) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        bar.doSomething(foo);
        return foo;
    }
}
```

There is a more elaborate example and discussion of this pattern at the following site [Java Practices->Don't pass 'this' out of a constructor](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=252)

Their example makes use of an example with an *Observer pattern*, where the instance being created will be registered with the *Observable*, but where the registrations shouldn't occur until after being fully instantiated.

Comment: I've rewritten my answer to include example code, while retaining the link to the related discussion and example. I noticed that the external link has a copyright and has declared that the code fragments have a BSD license. So it seems best to leave it alone rather than reprint it in the answer here.